# How to Update asp:Label after AJAX Callback

Tags: callback, asp.net-4.0

I'm using the ajaxtoolkit:Rating. It all works fine except I'm trying to write a value to an asp label on the changed event and can't get it to work. Here are the relevant lines of code:

page.aspx

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <td>
        <ajaxtoolkit:Rating ID="YourRating" runat="server" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior1" CurrentRating="0"
            MaxRating="10" StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
            ReadOnly="false" FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar"
            OnChanged="YourRating_Changed" />
    </td>
    <td>
        (<asp:Label ID="YourRatingNumber" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>)
    </td>
</LoggedInTemplate>
<AnonymousTemplate>
    <td>
     <a href="../Default.aspx">Login</a> or Register to Rate
    </td>
 </AnonymousTemplate>
```

page.aspx.cs

```
        protected void YourRating_Changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
    {
        ((HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("MainContent_LoginView1_YourRatingNumber")).InnerHtml = e.Value;

    }
```

What I'm trying to do is update my asp:label control named "YourRatingNumber" text to e.value. I've tried many ways. I realize the asp:label is rendered as a span tag but I can't seem to access that value either. How can do this?

Thanks ... Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous, meaning that a page load does not occur.  Changing the value of a label server-side during an AJAX operation causes nothing client side.  You would need to signal the client to update the page.  You should use javascript to do this.  I do not think you can do this using Web Forms.  If you use MVC, you can use their AJAX helpers to do this, but it would require rewriting the site.

I would suggest that you write some javascript to cause an AJAX event and have it update the label when it gets a response.  I would also suggest reading http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp, it explains how to use javascript to create AJAX requests, but you would need to tweak it a little to work with asp.net.

Also note, you should include whether you are using Web Forms or MVC, although they are similar, they have different handling of AJAX.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, thanks for your input. I am using Web Foms. I still think there's a way via my YourRating_Changed event using an UpdatePanel containing my asp:Label ID="YourRatingNumber. Of course I could just change AutoPostBack to true on ajaxtoolkit:Rating but that defeats the purpose of ajax. So how would I call a javascript function (or add one) using the e.callbackresult from the above YourRating_Changed block?

Comment: I put the the ajaxtoolkit rating control in an updatepanel and use the BehaviorID to call my JS function as: 

Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        $find("RatingBehavior1").add_EndClientCallback(function (sender, e) {
   document.getElementById('MainContent_LoginView1_YourRatingNumber').innerHTML = e.get_CallbackResult();
        });
 });

Works great now